# When I select a program, my chart disappears. What should I do?

Tags: charts, laravel-livewire

In my default dashboard, I select the first item (program), and everything works fine; my charts are displayed correctly. However, when I select another program, my chart disappears. But in my console, I'm able to retrieve its values, but the chart doesn't appear. How can I resolve this issue?

```
 public $program_id = "";
    public $activites = [];
    public $data = [];
    public $budget = [];
    public $documentCount = 0;

    public function render()
    {
        if ($this->program_id == "") {
            $program = Program::all()->first();
        } else {
            $program = Program::find($this->program_id);
        }

        if ($program) {
            $activites = $program->activities->groupBy('statut_id')->map->count();
            $statuts = Statut::whereIn('id', $activites->keys())->pluck('nom', 'id');

            $budgetProgramme = $program->budget;
            $this->documentCount = $program->documents->count();
            $budgetActivites = $program->activities->sum('budget');
            $this->budget = [
                'budget_programme' => $budgetProgramme,
                'budget_activite' => $budgetActivites,
            ];

            $this->data = [
                'cree' => $statuts->search('crée') !== false ? $activites->get($statuts->search('crée'), 0) : 0,
                'cours' => $statuts->search('en cours') !== false ? $activites->get($statuts->search('en cours'), 0) : 0,
                'finalisee' => $statuts->search('finalisée') !== false ? $activites->get($statuts->search('finalisée'), 0) : 0,
                'retard' => $statuts->search('retard') !== false ? $activites->get($statuts->search('retard'), 0) : 0,
            ];
            $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('updateChart', $this->data);
            $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('updateBudgetChart', $this->budget);

        }

        return view('livewire.programs.dashboard', [
            "programs" => Program::all(),
        ]);
    }

<div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h4 class="text-center"><span class="badge badge-secondary">Documents ressources total :{{$documentCount}} </span></h4>
                <hr>
                <div class="input-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Programme</span>
                    <select wire:model="program_id" id="program" class="form-control" required>

                        <option value="">Veuillez sélectionner le programme</option>
                        @foreach ($programs as $program)
                            <option value="{{ $program->id }}">
                                {{ $program->nom }}
                            </option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; height:50vh; width:100vw">
                            <canvas id="houseChart"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; height:40vh; width:80vw">
                            <canvas id="budgetHistogramme"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script>
        var houseChartCtx = document.getElementById('houseChart').getContext('2d');
        var houseChartData = {
            labels: ['Crée', 'En cours', 'Finalisé', 'En retard'],
            datasets: [{
                data: [
                    {{ $data['cree'] }},
                    {{ $data['cours'] }},
                    {{ $data['finalisee'] }},
                    {{ $data['retard'] }},
                ],
                backgroundColor: ['#3498DB', '#F39C12', '#00cc00', '#d9534f']
            }]
        };
        var myPieChart = new Chart(houseChartCtx, {
            type: 'pie',
            data: houseChartData
        });
        window.addEventListener('updateChart', data => {
            console.log(data);
            myPieChart.data.datasets[0].data = data;
            myPieChart.update();
            console.log("apres MAJ");
        });

        // section budget
        var budgetChartCtx = document.getElementById('budgetHistogramme').getContext('2d');
        var budgetChartData = {
            labels: ['Budget programme', 'Budget activités'],

            datasets: [{
                data: [
                    {{ $budget['budget_programme'] }},
                    {{ $budget['budget_activite'] }},
                ],
                backgroundColor: ['#3498DB', '#F39C12']
            }]
        };
        var budgetChart = new Chart(budgetChartCtx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: budgetChartData
        });
        window.addEventListener('updateBudgetChart', data => {
            console.log(data);
            budgetChart.data = data;
            budgetChart.update();
            console.log("budget apres MAJ");
        });
    </script>

</div>
```

I have searched on YouTube and on many sites, but nothing works

Comment: You probably want to look into `wire:ignore` on the chart's containers, so Livewire doesn't mess with their contents. Changes to the component will re-render the HTML, which'll remove the previously initialized charts.

Comment: "I added wire:ignore, but nothing is working.